# Passing the address to a function and the values did not change after modification

Tags: c

Here's the code:

this function is for reverse a array.

```
void rev(int* nums, int count){

for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
    int temp = *(nums+i);
    *(nums+i) = *(nums+count-1-i);
    *(nums+count-1-i) = temp;
}
}
```

this one is for implementing the function rev().

```
void rotate(int* nums, int numsSize, int k) {
    int*q = nums;
    int count = numsSize - k;
    rev(nums, count);
    q = q+k;

    rev(q, k);
    rev(nums, numsSize);

}
```

I pass the address of the array in `rev()`, but when it goes out of the for loop of `rev()`, `nums[]` did not change.

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why would you do that at all. Why not just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl not in C.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I was using c not cpp.

Comment: @SouravGhosh But the question is tagged C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It was...not anymore.

Comment: @JesperJuhl At first I want to get more attention so I tagged cpp. I deleted it already.

Comment: That's not how tags work.

Comment: @Bender you should not do that.

Comment: @SenDjasni Yes I realized it right away I posted it.  I thought it was a pointer problem so I tagged c and cpp. I won't do this anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rev()` reverse the array twice, which means that the array remaing original.

You can resolve this by changing the loop condition `i<count` to `i<count-1-i`.

Answer (score 1):

You are double reversing ;) The loop has to stop in the middle of the array